# How to set click events in WebKitX ActiveX control in C++

Tags: c++, webkit, activex

I am using WebKitX ActiveX control for displaying web page in MFC Dialog. Now i want to set click events for same. I am setting click events using below code :

```
m_ctrlWebKit.SetEvents(m_ctrlWebKit.DOM_EVENT_CLICK || m_ctrlWebKit.DOM_EVENT_DBLCKICK);
```

But when i click on web page i always get only click event not double click. So can anyone tell me how to do it.

Answer (score -1):

WebKitX - Getting Started with C++
https://www.webkitx.com/doc/light/Getting%20Started%20with%20CPP.html

I hope this helps!

Comment: Please avoid posting links as answer.